# wxPython ToolBar with disabled tools not rendering as expected

Tags: python, wxpython

I've got a wxPython based application and am having trouble with one of the toolbars.  It was originally written against wxPython 2.8.10/Python 2.6, but is currently running with wxPython 4.0.4/Python 2.7.15.

The toolbar contains both (16,16) and (32,32) bitmaps.  When everything is enabled, all the bitmaps render fine.  However any bitmap that is disabled looks like it is trying to render in the top left (16,15) corner of its space.    I've tried switching to call (16,16) bitmaps, and I've tried setting bmpDisabled to various values, and changing the SetToolBitmapSize on the toolbar, but nothing seems to fix the behavior.

Example of the toolbar rendering when enabled

[image: Example of the toolbar rendering when enabled]

Example of the toolbar with the 1st (16,16) and 3rd (32,32) disabled.  2nd (16,16) still enabled.

[image: Example of the toolbar with the 1st (16,16) and 3rd (32,32) disabled]

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
   self._tb = self.CreateToolBar()
   self._tb.SetToolBitmapSize((32,32))

   image =   getTransparentwxBitmap("icons/foo.bmp")
   item =   self._tb.AddCheckTool(self.TB_FOO_ID, "", image, wx.NullBitmap, "Foo Panel", "Show/Hide the foo panel")
    self._tb.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL,self.onToolClick,item)
    self._tb.EnableTool(self.TB_FOO_ID,False)

   image =   getTransparentwxBitmap("icons/bar.bmp")
   item =   self._tb.AddCheckTool(self.TB_BAR_ID, "", image, wx.NullBitmap, "Bar Panel", "Show/Hide the bar panel")
   self._tb.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL,self.onToolClick,item)
   self._tb.EnableTool(self.TB_BAR_ID,False)

   imgPath = "images/baz.png"
   image = wx.Bitmap(imgPath)
   item = self._tb.AddTool(self.TB_BAZ_ID, "", image, shortHelp="BAZ Tool")
   self._tb.EnableTool(self.TB_BAZ_ID, False)
   .
   .
   .
   other tools
   .
   .
   .

   self._tb.Realize()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll assume that you are on MSW, try not supplying the `wx.NullBitmap` parameter and utilise images that are all consistent with your `SetToolBitmapSize` setting.

Comment: Ah, I knew I forgot something, yes I was running under Win7.

Anyway, I tried both removing the 32x32 images (which still saw the problem) and then replacing all the 16x16 ones with 32x32, which actually worked.  

So I am thinking something was wrong  or odd with one of the 16x16 images, or maybe it did not like mixing BMP and PNGs.  Either way, rendering correctly now.

Comment: From the docs `The Windows-specific toolbar classes expect 16-colour bitmaps that are 16 pixels wide and 15 pixels high. If you want to use a different size, call wx.ToolBar.SetToolBitmapSize as the demo shows, before adding tools to the button bar. Don’t supply more than one bitmap for each tool, because the toolbar generates all three images (normal, depressed, and checked) from the single bitmap you give it.`